# How to handle session timeout when a device was suspended in an Ajax app?

Tags: ajax, session-timeout

It's easy enough to build an Ajax app which checks all responses to make sure they aren't indicative of a session expiry, and if the session has expired automatically log the user out with a friendly "Your session timed out due to inactivity" error message.

But a common occurrence in Ajax applications is that:

1. User is logged in, happily using app, retrieving data over http with an established http session
2. User closes laptop
3. Host times out http session after N minutes
4. User reopens laptop later on.  Ajax app appears alive and well.  They click around which is just fine since the app lets them see things they've already loaded.
5. Then, they click on something that requires data to be loaded, and the data comes back indicating session expiration
6. The Ajax app kicks them out and says "Your session timed out due to inactivity".

This is really weird to the user because they *were not* inactive from their point of view.

Now, one possibility is to have Javascript code in the client which uses setTimeout() to periodically (say, every 15 minutes if the session timeout is 30 minutes) trigger a request to the host to ask how much time is left in the session.  This periodic check is great because it lets you show them a warning when they are close to timing out, e.g. "You're session will time out in 1 minute unless you do something".

But that doesn't help when the user's machine is suspended.  That's because according to all my testing in many different browsers, setTimeout time applies to elapsed running time instead of elapsed real time.  That is, if you call setTimeout("alert('hi')",2*60*1000); and then suspend your machine 10 seconds later, wait 5 minutes, and reactivate your machine, you'll have wait 110 more seconds until you get that alert (I have not been able to find definitive documentation of this behavior but it is a demonstrable fact).  So that means your period check may not happen for quite after the user's machine resumes.

My solution to this is to, instead of having my periodic check based on on a long setTimeout, instead do a short setTimeout (say, every 5 seconds), and check the elapsed time since the last check using new Date().getTime() to get the actual clock time.  This way I am always checking against the real clock, and instead of the client waiting from zero to fifteen minutes before realizing it has timed out after a suspension, at most it will wait about five seconds (plus http response time) to find out.

But I dislike this solution because it relies on a frequent timer based interruption.  *Is there a smarter way to handle this?*

Answer (score 1):

With big sites like facebook, which is rich with interactive updates, you'll find that there is a combination of all sorts different mechanisms. I'd guess that they're doing validation both on API requests and on Push requests (since someone once told me they use push in addition to ajax)

Timeouts: One thing to consider is that  if you store session data in a cookie, having that cookie expire is the same as no longer being logged in. Since the cookie is a hashed value of a few things like a user ID, or a timestamp, it is really easy to see that a session is no longer valid on the very first function call to the API.

Long polling: if a site uses long polling in which a connection is opened indefinitely to await a response from the web server, then closing your computer would kill that connection.

However, if they're just doing regular ajax polling with a reoccurring function call via setInterval, then the web server would automatically know whether the user should get data in return based on the timestamp in their hashed cookie, assuming there is one to check. Those are the types of things that get sent in the header.

Some services actually update a database field that stores your timestamp of last activity and then expires if a certain amount of time has elapsed. This is a less efficient way to do it since it keep track of state.

There's really quite a few ways sites do these things.

Comment: long polling would probably be a good solution in a number of areas beyond this as well, but the webserver we use doesn't support it well...

Comment: i dont think any traditional webserver really supports long polling well yet.... something like node.js would probably be better for that. If i were you, I'd just validate the cookie on a time interval. I recently saw an app where they made an ajax ping function to basically validate the loggedInCookie every minute or so. it works like a charm.